# How can I find suggested edits from before account creation?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, profile-page, user-accounts, sign-up

As an anonymous user, I made a suggested edit on **Server Fault**.  Something
came up suggesting creating an account to save the reputation.  I clicked it,
registered and confirmed by the emailed link.

I do not remember what the edit was and would like to see it, but it does not
show under `Server Fault -> profile -> all actions`.

[It seems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287413/10095231) that the [data api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits) could be used for it, but it requires
knowing the post/answer/question id.

Is there a way to see what it was and if it was accepted/rejected?

Comment: Checking your browser history is a good first step. Failing that, if you still feel it’s worth the time, someone with sufficient reputation on that site could look at the list of recent edit reviews and tell you, but you’d have to give them enough info so they would know which edit you’re looking for.

Comment: Try logging out of your account and navigating to the post you were editing, and check to see if the banner appears.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, but I registered over 2 months ago and from another computer (I still have the emailed link though).

Comment: Ah, unfortunately it will be impossible to get that link by yourself. I did some testing and confirmed that the banner status is saved in a cookie, which you of course won't have access to since you're on a different computer.

Comment: But how is the registered user linked to the edit then? Isn't the anonymous user merged into the registered account?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas though, will try to see if I still have the history/cookie on the other computer on Monday.

Comment: You can't claim edits made anonymously into an account. What the banner means is that you can create an account to earn reputation for your *future* edits.

Answer (score 1):

Edits made by anonymous users can be found in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer in the SuggestedEdits table. Unfortunately edits you suggested before you created an account will not be assigned retroactively to your userprofile.

If you don't know which post you edited and only have a rough date range [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/1248017) is the best option to give you a list of potential edits by anonymous users.

```sql
select se.postid [Post Link]
     , concat('site://review/suggested-edits/', rt.id, '|review') [review link]
     , se.creationdate
     , approvaldate
     , rejectiondate
     , comment
     , text
from suggestededits se
left  outer join reviewtasks rt 
   on rt.suggestedEditid = se.id
   and rt.postid = se.postid
where se.creationdate between '2018-04-01' and '2018-07-29'
and owneruserid is null 
and comment not like '%@gmail.com'
order by se.creationdate desc
```

If you find your edit, the approval or rejection date tells you what happened with it.

This is what the result looks like:

[image: resultt]

You have to inspect just under 100 edits to find the one you submitted, assuming your recollection of the timeframe is correct.